# How do you create a timing script that you can end by changing a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, benchmarking

Using: Python 3.7 on Windows 10

I am making an algorithm that solves mazes. I want to be able to start a timer script when I start the algorithm, and stop when I change a variable, say 'stop'.

The structure of my program is as follows:

```
import dependencies
algorithm 1
algorithm 2
algorithm 3
algorithm 4
solution
results
```

On the results screen, the times for each algorithm would be displayed.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction to creating such a timing script? Thx!

P.S. If you wish for more details about the circuit, feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) to get the time delta:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.now()
your_algorithm()
delta = datetime.now() - start
```

Considering that your algorithm interrupts the execution when the `stop` flag is raised.

Comment: Thx very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, tough on StackOverflow it is custom to avoid "thank you" comments (that in some situation measure in the decades in number) and to just use the upvote/accept mechanism. Have a nice day!